# when initializing view in fragment i got a nullpointerException at getcontext()

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-view, android-context

I'm initialing imageview at DailyCardView.java which are called by a fragment. But it keeps showing nullPointerException. I really don't know where went wrong... Guys help me><

I tried getRootView() to get view of Fragment so i can code:iv=(ImageView)getRootView().findViewById(R.id.iv);
But it still not work.

```
**//Fragment**
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.home_fragment, container, false);
    dailyStackLayout = (DailyStackLayout)view.findViewById(R.id.dailyStackLayout);
    dailyStackLayout.setDatas(dailyFoodList);
    return view;
}

**//DailyStackLayout**
public DailyStackLayout(Context context) {
    this(context, null);
}
public DailyStackLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    this(context, attrs, 0);
}
public DailyStackLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    init();
}

public void init() {
    params = new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    scaleY = DensityUtil.dip2px(getContext(), BASESCALE_Y_VALUE);
}
public void setDatas(List<DailyFood> dailyFoodList) {
    this.dailyFoodList = dailyFoodList;
    if (dailyFoodList == null) {
        return;
    }
    for (int i = index; index < i + STACK_SIZE; index++) {
        dc = new DailyCardView(getContext());
        dc.bind(dailyFoodList.get(index));
    }
}

**//DailyCardView**
public DailyCardView(Context context) {
    super(context, null);
}
public DailyCardView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    this(context, attrs,0);
}

public DailyCardView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) 
{
    super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    init(context);
}

public void init(Context context) {
    if (!isInEditMode()) {
        inflate(context, R.layout.item_daily_card, this);
        iv = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.iv);
    }
}
public void bind(DailyFood dailyFood) { 
    if (dailyFood == null) {return;}
    if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(dailyFood.getId())) {
        Glide.with(**iv.getContext()**)  // **NullPointerException**!
                .load(Constant.Daily_URL+dailyFood.getId()+".jpg")
                .into(iv);
}
```

I expect to load the image right but it went wrong at getContext().

Comment: iv is defined at R.layout.item_daily_card.

Answer (score 0):

```
dc = new DailyCardView(getContext());
```

This calls the `DailyCardView(Context)` constructor that does not call `init()`:

```
public DailyCardView(Context context) {
    super(context, null);
}
```

The `init()` call would init `iv`. And then you call `bind()` that assumes that `iv` is initialised. Bang, NPE.

Either change the `super` in the constructor to `this` to delegate to another constructor that calls `init()`, or just add a call to `init()`.

Comment: thanks!!! Problem solved!! I'm really stupid... thanks!!!